# How to change window title from a frame in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I hosted my web app on a freehoster service which shows my webpage in a frameset. 2 frames are there. In the top narrow frame there are their ad and the bottom frame is mine. I can set the title in the admin panel but it always remains the same regardless what is in my title tag. Setting `document.title` in javascript not works. But if I break out from the frameset using the ff's This frame/show option it will change the window/tab title as expected.

So is it possible to change the parent document's title from my frame?

(background: it will be an ajax board game and I want to notify the user somehow when it's his turn.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, but it has to be on the same domain (and use a relative url for a path)

```
  window.parent.document.title = "Your new title";
```

If the iframe/frame is on a different domain, then you'll get a permission denied error.

Comment: It seems the hoster placed the page under a different domain so I got the permission denied error. It seems I need to look for a different approach...

Answer (score 5):

use top.document.title (top refers to the top most window within the browser)