# Is there a way to change the title of index.html from page in the frame by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frame, frameset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change window title from a frame in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150035/how-to-change-window-title-from-a-frame-in-javascript)

In my index.html file I have 3 frames.

I want to change the title of index.html from one of the pages in frames.

How could this be done by using JavaScript?

Comment: Did you mean `<iframe>`?

Comment: @Jimmy X, no, frames in frameset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it has to be on the same domain (and use a relative url for a path)

```
window.parent.document.title = "Your new title";
```

If the iframe/frame is on a different domain, then you'll get a permission denied error.

If the above fails, use

use `top.document.title` (top refers to the top most window within the browser)