# Change page's title when using 2 frames

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application in CakePHP and I have 2 frames in a frame set, like this:

```
<frameset rows="32px, *" frameborder="no">
  <frame src="<?=Router::url('/frame/player', true); ?>" class="foo" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0">
  <frame src="<?=Router::url('/pages/index', true); ?>" class="foo"  scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0">
</frameset>
```

The first frame owns the page's title. In the second one I have my application. The first frame is an audio player and I used this because my client wanted an audio player which wouldn't stop when switching pages(views) in the application(I don't like this, but he wanted it). The second frame runs the application like a charm. My problem is: When I switch views, page's title doesn't change with them(because the first frame owns it).

Is there a way to set page's title from the other frame(which runs the application)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 4 points from being able to comment, or this would be a comment.

[How to change window title from a frame in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150035/how-to-change-window-title-from-a-frame-in-javascript)