# Javascript code for changing browser's tab title not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, I can't find the problem or issue why I cannot use simple javascript code to update browser's tab text.

I'm doing a Shopify Application using Rails, which will be embedded and iframed to shopify.

I have a simple function to update tab title.

```
ex.
// jquery lib is loaded already....
$(function){ // i tried window on load as well 
  document.title = 'Sample';
}
```

But running it in browser's console has no problem.

No error shows in console, but not working... confusing...
I tried to make simple html file and it works there, only having issue when i put the code in my rails app, that being iframed in Shopify.

Any idea out there?

Comment: @aldrien  you need to get the parent window then try to change the title. Because you're changing in the iFrame so it won't reflect in the main tab.

Comment: Without a way to reproduce the issue nobody can help you

Comment: @AnilTalla i see your point `window.parent.document.title` :)
 unfortunately, I can't access it, getting Blocked a frame with origin "https : //zzz" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Is there other way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change window title from a frame in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150035/how-to-change-window-title-from-a-frame-in-javascript)

Comment: @GalAbra yes, I'm about to change the title of my question :)

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to access the parent document, if the iFrame gets served from a different domain.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann yah, seems no other way tsssk... :(

Comment: a stupid solution would be to nest it in yet another new (refreshed) window with the title passed in.  it has its own pitfalls though.